# Nvidia driver issues persistent across multiple versions of ubuntu - unbootable OS

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia, nouveau

On June 6th after installing a software update, nothing on steam was able to launch, so I rebooted my PC. after that point, it consistently got stuck on the motherboard logo when trying to boot the OS. I was able to recover my files by using an older version of the kernel that forced llvmpipe. This was on 20.10.

After recovering my files, I put on a fresh installation of 21.04, only to find the same problem, which triggers when I try to change the driver from nouveau to the proprietary nvidia drivers from the additional drivers gui, either the standard 460 or the beta 465 branch. running lshw - c video reveals that the driver doesn't change from nouveau, and the OS becomes unbootable if restarted with the additional drivers gui set to the proprietary nvidia drivers.

I have changed the 21.04 window manager from wayland to x11 to prevent any incompatibility issues.

When either the old OS or the new one become unbootable, I can still access GRUB, but they will not boot up even under safe mode. Changing to a slightly older kernel did not make a difference, only when I went so old that the driver was forced to change was I able to access my machine.

Comment: You can install Ubuntu and choose proprietary software and Nvidia drivers during installation and in that case you do not have to switch from nouveau

Comment: This solution is ineffective, ubuntu is forced into llvmpipe mode and set to nouveau driver when i install additional drivers during installation. It also defaults to x11, and continues to render itself unbootable when trying to switch to the proprietary drivers.

In this state, it no longer even recognizes that my GPU exists

Answer (score 0):

In the past, I have got the same problem when I start the Ubuntu OS installation (after GRUB freeze the USB/ black screen).

In my case, I'm using a powerfull Laptop as principal PC, and I discovered - occasionally - that the problems was related to the external Monitors attached. This because, at really beginning of the installation, your Nvidia Graphic doesn't work properly and the graphic power it's limitated, it works once Ubuntu installation will start and detect all the hardwares/ drivers. On 20.04 was the same problem. I suggest you, if you have a laptop, to use the principal build-in display during the Ubuntu OS installation.

If not, and you have normal PC, try to connect just one monitor and choose the most easy connection like HDMI, not miniDisplay Port or wherever....

And I noticed that, when you will reinstall the OS, try to use another PC or OS to clean well the SSD/HDD where you are going to install again your OS, you have to erease and fill it with all 0 bytes, because I have got also this experience that even if you will erease in normal way the same SSD/HDD that previosly you have installed Ubuntu OS, in some way it still to persist to find some currapted file system from the previous Ubuntu installation.

Comment: Thanks to your suggestion, I discovered that I can boot in with nvidia drivers and use them effectively, so long as only the HDMI monitor is plugged in. Trying to plug in the displayport cable is then what bricks the OS, and renders it unbootable. Should I make another question at this point? The system is usable, but only on the backup monitor

Comment: Because you restored and try to fix the Nvidia drivers, and because I made something like you in the past. My best advice to your situation, (if you can) save your important things and wipe completely your SSD/HDD, but not just wipe in normal procedure ; you should wipe in secure way and fill with all "0 byte" the SSD/HDD make it with another PC/OS and specific software for wipe --->

Comment: ---> Because, in the past I have made two times this fixing trying and when i messed up with Kernel or Nvidia Drivers, it seems sometimes that Ubuntu on next new installation can still read the wiped currapted files and keep you with the problems, you are like in a loop situation, even with the new installation. So, Wipe/ Erease it and fill it with 0 bytes method. And on next fresh installation use the basic HDMI and only when yoiu will finish completely all the Ubuntu installation plug-in your miniDisplayPort or DisplayPort or wherever...

Comment: I went through the process of zeroing out my SSD with a liveboot usb, but the issue remains the same. having the DisplayPort connected at any point while also having nvidia drivers active continues to break the computer.

Comment: Did you check in NVIDIA X Server, if you need to set some "Auto" voice under the Monitor Section, or some Hrz Settings from the Monitor it changes automatically? Also, which Nvidia Graphic Card we talking about? Do you have 4k Monitor? Do you use the DPI Fractional Scale?

Comment: Everything is set to automatic in nvidia x server, i see nothing out of the ordinary. The card is a geforce 2070 rtx, and the problematic monitor in question is a 4k monitor, of the same benQ brand as the other one, and it uses displayport. I am not using fractional scaling.
should also mention that i'm not using wayland, since i already know that causes problems with nvidia cards. instead i'm using gnome 3.38.5.

Comment: If you are using the right Drivers from Ubuntu (instead of from Nvidia site) and you are sure of all the steps that you did. In this case the circle of the problem starting to be close/smaller in few topics. I just give you some idea, with my GTX 1070 I'm using the miniDisplayport - HDMI with one high level Acer 4k Monitor (not sure if one period Benq and Acer was sharing the same thechnology behind) so what I'm tryng to say it's ----->

Comment: ----> at the beginning I have bought one expensive cable Displayport to discovered that it gives me the problems, and I found that was defective, but to be sure at that time I called Acer to let me change the Monitor as well because the DisplayPort area startinng to don't working as well. So, in the end, I have changed the Displayport cable and fixed temporary the problem + the monitor because was defective the unique DisplauPort connection. From this experience, try to test your DisplayPort cable somewhere else and try your DisplayPort Connection Monitor with another OS like Windows--->

Comment: ---> to understand that it's not the Monitor Connection or even the Graphic Card Display Connection. If not all of those things, the unique problem will be focused to the Nvidia drivers for the 2070 rtx, and we can be sure that will be that. But first I suggest you to try these above tests..... ;)

Comment: So, running tests you suggested, I have discovered that the main 4k monitor is able to run with the nvidia drivers, so long as it's plugged in using the other monitor's hdmi cable.

the other monitor doesn't have a displayport outlet for me to test that particular monitor with both nvidia drivers and displayport, but we've narrowed the bug down to only when it's the 4k monitor, using HDMI

Comment: Good to know @Kott, excuse me for the stupid question, but did you tried in Ubuntu settings to give as Single and principal Display to the 4k Monitor with the DisplayPort connection? And lastly because I know that Nvidia with Linux it's not the best , but please try to give the same Primary Display to the Monitor with the DisplayPort in NVIDIA X Server Settings, because even if you change it in Ubuntu Settings, could be that Nvidia Drivers as preset in "Auto", the drivers changes the Displays--->

Comment: --->   I saw it last time this problems, with AMD no problems about but NVIDIA Drivers go in one Way and Ubuntu Settings in another and could creat the Display Conflict Settings. Try this and your 4k Monitor should work even if you plug the HDMI, the Important it's that you don't let the System or the NVIDIA X Server Settings to change it AUTOMATICALLY. Because as i said, could create some conflicts to each other (it's absurd but unfortunately it's NVIDIA problem)...

Answer (score 0):

The problem was worked around by ordering new cables, such that no connection ran displayport to displayport.